# python deleting the start of the string if beginning with " " or ","

Tags: python

I want to make a function check if a string starts with " " or "," and then delete those until it reaches a letter for example

I want to turn the string

```
" , , abcd" into
"abcd"

or ",,,,,      abcd" into
"abcd"
```

Answer (score 5):

Use lstrip() function as:

```
>>> test = " , , abcd"
>>> test.lstrip(" ,")
'abcd'
```

Thanks to who remind me.

strip() function will remove both the leading and trailing characters

lstrip() function will remove only the leading ones

rstrip() function will remove only the trailing one.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `strip()` will strip from both sides, `lstrip()` only strips from the left:

```
>>> " , , abcd".lstrip(' ,')
'abcd'
>>> ",,,,,      abcd".lstrip(' ,')
'abcd'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions posted here will work if it's only spaces and commas. If you want to remove every non-alphanumeric character, you can use a regex like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^[^\w]+(.*?)[^\w]+$')
```

Alternatively, if it's only letters you want to allow, replace `\w` with `A-Za-z`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^[^A-Za-z]+(.*?)[^A-Za-z]+$')
```

To use it now, do this:

```
str = re.sub(pattern, '\\1', str)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [15]: s = " , , abcd"

In [23]: s.strip(', ')
Out[23]: 'abcd'

In [24]: s = ",,,,,      abcd"

In [25]: s.strip(', ')
Out[25]: 'abcd'
```

Answer (score -1):

I have to use split function to do this:

string = ",, ,,,      abcd"

print (string.split(' '))[-1]